# К вопросу о свойствах русского языка (7)

Tags: орфография, троллинг

Предположим, я предложу, чтобы русские писали "помоему" вместо "по-моему", "потвоему" вместо "по-твоему", "понашему" вместо "по-нашему", "повашему" вместо "по-вашему".

**Вопрос:** Противоречит ли указанное предложение хотя бы одному свойству русского языка?

P.S.

1. Русский язык является государственным языком в Республике Беларусь. Но я не планирую заставлять белорусов писать "помоему" вместо "по-моему".
2. Несомненно, предложение "По-моему, краткость - сестра таланта." менее лаконично, чем предложение "Помоему, краткость - сестра таланта.".
3. Наречие "несомненно" пишется без дефиса.
4. Наречия "по-моему", "по-нашему" и т. п. образованы от притяжательных местоимений "мой", "наш" и т. п., тогда как наречия "поэтому", "потому", "посему" образованы от  местоимений "этот", "тот", "сей".

Comment: Ну, предложите. А предположим, я - не соглашусь. Не стоит переиначивать язык по формальным правилам. Пусть живет.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Формально предложения не противоречат свойствам р.языка, а вот информация, содержащаяся в них, противоречит  свойству подчинения написания слов правилам орфографии. Правила орфографии подчиняются свойству языка учитывать исторические закономерности его развития, законы словообразования. Наречия на -ому, -ему, -цки,-ски, образованные приставочно-суффиксальным способом с переходом предлога в приставку,пишутся через дефис, чтобы сохранить следы этого перехода: по моему разумению = по-моему. Сохраняется логика образования наречий (два слова объединились в одно и застыли, стали неизменяемым словом). Если будет написано слитно, эта логика уйдёт.

Лаконичность здесь ни при чём. Здесь работает свойство языка ИЗБЫТОЧНОСТЬ- в написании сохраняются достаточные сведения об истории слова, его семантике, морфологических свойствах.

Наречие "несомненно"пишется без дефиса, потому что было устаревшее слово сомненно, а с частицей НЕ оно приобрело противоположное значение.Слово было одно и осталось одно - зачем дефис, объединяющий два слова в одно?

Comment: Большое спасибо.

Comment: >"Формально предложения не противоречат свойствам р.языка"  
  
р.- это река? ранение? Раша?   

Кстати, поскольку что такое "свойства" все понимают по0-разному, то и само заявление бессодержательно. 
Я считаю, что у русского языка есть свойство "писать грамотно". 
Этому свойству предложения г-на тролля противоречат.

Comment: Свойство "писать грамотно" может быть только у человека. И у Галактиона оно, кстати, есть (опечаток у него не больше, чем у вас).

@behemothus, не кормите троллей (с).

Comment: Я не возражаю, чтобы местные мэтры спорили между собой о свойстве "писать грамотно".